# Redirect a WP to another with all URL

Tags: redirect, htaccess

i'm bad at redirection so i'm asking you.

I have my old site with some posts like www.oldsite.com/category/my-awesome-post, www.oldsite.com/category/my-awesome-post-2 ...

I would like to redirect each URL to a new domain like www.newsite.com/category/my-awesome-post

so all URL will be redirect dynamiccaly.

Is it possible.

Thank you

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ ?

Comment: downvoted since it shows no research. Have you tried to google? have you tried any of the solutions there?

Answer (score 0):

If you want 301/302 redirect sitewide my suggestion is to use .htaccess file, but that's not a good practice at all. Anyway the code should be something like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^OLDDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://NEWDOMAIN.com [R=301,L]
```

Note: Change the R=301 to whatever you would want where R=301 would mean permanent redirect and R=302 would mean temprorary redirect.

If you want to migrate your site to a new wp install on another domain, you need to use the WP Migrate DB plugin that can be found here : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

The plugin do a really dirty job of replacing every single url in your db with a new one, which by hand is not really cool process.. You then need to import the db via phpMyAdmin or other interface to the new place and change all static links on the pages if there are any.

Answer (score -2):

Please try to check the below links:

> http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-creating-redirects-in-wordpress/
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819706/redirect-all-traffic-to-root-of-another-domain
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain
>
> https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362458/redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255967/htaccess-redirect-all-requests-to-different-domain
>
> http://www.orderofbusiness.net/blog/redirect-old-domain-to-new-domain-via-htaccess/

Comment: links by themselves are not a real answer.